# Persistindo no Banco a partir de um arquivo

Tags: java, postgresql

Qual seria a forma mais eficiente de ler um arquivo e gravar no banco Postgres? Estou postando um código onde consigo fazer, porém o postgres me limita no número de conexão.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora segue o erro:

```
Set 12, 2016 8:53:39 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
ERROR: HHH000299: Could not complete schema update
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: sorry, too many clients already
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:398)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:173)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:64)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:136)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:29)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:21)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:31)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:24)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:410)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:280)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:509)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1799)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:915)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:900)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:59)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47)
    at factory.ProdutorEntityManager.<init>(ProdutorEntityManager.java:10)
    at com.arquivo.Ler.main(Ler.java:25)

Set 12, 2016 8:53:39 AM org.hibernate.ejb.internal.EntityManagerFactoryRegistry addEntityManagerFactory
WARN: HHH000436: Entity manager factory name (bd) is already registered.  If entity manager will be clustered or passivated, specify a unique value for property 'hibernate.ejb.entitymanager_factory_name'
Set 12, 2016 8:53:39 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 53300
Set 12, 2016 8:53:39 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: FATAL: sorry, too many clients already
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
```

Desculpe segue o Código:

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException  {

```
    List<Dados> arquivo = new ArrayList<Dados>();
    Dados d = new Dados();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader("C:\\ler/arquivo1.txt")).useDelimiter("\\||\\n");


    try {

        while (scanner.hasNext()) {

            ProdutorEntityManager mf = new ProdutorEntityManager();

               d.setId(null);   
               d.setNome(scanner.next());
               d.setCidade(scanner.next());
               d.setEstado(scanner.next());
               arquivo.add(d);

               mf.manager.getTransaction().begin();
               mf.manager.persist(d);
               mf.manager.getTransaction().commit();
               mf.manager.close();

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Comment: Poste o código na pergunta também, sem ele não da pra analisar o problema.

Comment: Como o @Leonardo disse, você não precisa instanciar um novo EntityManager a cada loop do while.

Comment: Postar o código significa colocar o texto dele e não imagem.

Comment: E como eu faria pois se coloco a instância fora do while não roda (ver comentário abaixo) e imagino que não consiga guardar uns 10.000 obj em memória para depois persisti-los.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que se você mover a instrução `ProdutoEntityManager mf = new ProdutoEntityManager();` para fora do while, vai funcionar, pois não existe a necessidade de criar diversos `EntityManager` para persistir mais de um objeto, sendo assim não vai ocorrer mais essa sua exceção.

Comment: Já fiz isso acontece que o método "mf.manager.close();" fecha a conexão na primeira passado do while e não permite a persistencia. Tentei também colocar o metodo acima fora do while porem recebo a seguinte exceção.

Comment: Já fiz isso porem na primeira fez que percorre o while o método "mf.manager.close();" fecha a conexão, já tentei colocar o mesmo método fora do while no entanto esta é a exceção que recebo:                                INFO: HHH000232: Schema update complete
Hibernate: select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
Hibernate: insert into Dados (cidade, estado, nome, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Error while committing the transaction

Comment: Remova também a instrução `mf.manager.close();`  para fora do while.

Comment: Outra pergunta, isso é uma aplicação Web?

Comment: Não é web. Já fiz isso quando coloco fora do while tenho esta exceção: Error while committing the transaction

Comment: Me da uma descrição melhor do stackerror.

Comment: Me mostra como está o mapeamento das suas entidades, provavelmente  é algo no mapeamento.

Comment: Pessoal consegui resolver era o que vcs falaram porem tinha que instaciar a Classe do objeto dentro do while.

Comment: Agora que vi aquele `dados` do lado de foro, sim faz sentido.

Comment: vlw sou novo em desenvolvimento e no site preciso fechar este topico?

Comment: Não, é só interessante fazer o que você fez que é marcar a pergunta como respondida e marcar a resposta como útil.